# Additional principal payment split between interest and principal

Tags: united-states, mortgage, interest, amortization, principal

I made an additional payment with my first mortgage payment but I noticed that although I designated the additional payment, say **$10**, as principal the remaining principal balance didn't go down by the exact amount. Based on the numbers the split was:

- principal `$8.56`
- interest `$1.44`

Is this normal? Did I misunderstand what the `principal` designation means?

**EDIT:** My servicer agreed that it was improperly classified and they fixed the error. Note to others - they can make mistakes.

Comment: I would have thought they are referring to the accumulated interest which has become part of the principal, but 14.4% seems a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I made an additional payment with my first mortgage payment

I have found it is much clearer if the additional payment is done as either a separate check, or as a separate transfer. I make my additional principal payment as an additional transfer a few days after the required payment. I still have to specify that it is to reduce the principal. One advantage of the transfer is that I can automate it.

I would contact the mortgage payment processor, to make sure everbody is clear about the procedure and your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Read your loan documents or reach out to your lender.

Usually there's a minimum amount you need to meet before it's applied to the principal and/or you need to flag it explicitly.